# Foundation 6.4.1 - How to make the dropdown menu centre under its parent?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, zurb-foundation

I am trying to achieve a dropdown menu like this [site](http://www.christies.com/), where I can centerise the dropdown menu :[image]

This is my working code and it is far from perfect yet:

```css
.row,
.grid-container {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.menu>li>a {
  line-height: 40px;
}

.menu>li>a:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

.menu ul li a {
  line-height: normal;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu ul li:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.1/css/foundation.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.1/js/foundation.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <ul class="menu align-center dropdown" data-dropdown-menu>
    <li>
      <a href="#">One</a>
      <ul class="menu vertical">
        <li><a href="#">One One One One One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).foundation();
</script>
```

As you can see `menu vertical` is not centerised - only the text is. How can I make it centre **under its parent**?

Also, how can I **remove** the dropdown arrow that is next to `one`?

Or any customise-able CSS plugin that I can use to achieve this result, instead of re-inventing it, or using Foundation (it is quite a challenge to customise it!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this after the current style rules for this after will get rid of the arrow (you could use an important if you can't get it after the correct rule declarations in the style block, but i suggest against it)

```
.dropdown.menu > li.is-dropdown-submenu-parent > a::after{
  content: none;
}
```

And that site uses dynamically calculated left values on the element to place it centered, you could achieve your desired effect by something like this

```
.dropdown.menu > li.opens-right > .is-dropdown-submenu{
   margin-left: -65px;
}
```

Comment: sorry, does it mean that I have to calculate this figure `margin-left: -65px;`?

Comment: You could just eyeball it, change the margins on each individual dropdown until they look correct, might have to use some media queries to target the same elements at skinnier (or wider) page widths